# Html table cell size (or cell height that fits its content)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net, html-table

I want to put 3 vertical options in a listview. I use a table to accomplish that but only 2 options are visible so I need to compress the cell height. You can see in the picture that there is a free space in each cell.

[image]

I've tried some td options like height but no succeded.
Can I use some other html control, maybe a list, to get what i want?
am.

Comment: It would probably help if you showed the html that you are using to create this page.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using a table to create the vertical options, the best you can do to compress the height (besides using smaller font, of course) is to set the cell padding and cell spacing to something small:

```
<table cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1">
<tr> 
   etc...
```

Comment: I tried it but doesn't change the height. What about using a list?